# Node/Angular url-rewrite not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url-rewriting

I am pretty new to angular/node. That being said I am having an issue where refreshing my page just returns a JSON body which is being served up from my webserver.

I have tried creating middleware so that my index.html is an entry point for the application but for some reason on this particular page it does not want to work.

app.js

```
    //set up web server
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.port || 5000;
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname);

//init body parser
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
//serve up static css/js files from public directory
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/src'));


//init sql
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = require('./dbconfig');

sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err !== null) {
        console.log(err);
    };
});


//set up routes
var searchRouter = require('./src/webserver/routes/searchRoutes')();
app.use('/search', searchRouter);


app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(rootPath + '/src/index.html');
  // res.render(rootPath + '/src/index.html');
  });

 //start server
app.listen(port, function (err) {
console.log('running server on port ' + port);
});
```

searchService.js - this is a service which is sending a json response to the client. There is a route and controller bewteen this code handling the response.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var searchService = function () {

function searchIssues(req, res, searchterm) {
    var fetch = 50; //show 50 results at a time
    var offset = 0; //will extract out of request eventually
    var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement();
    ps.input('searchterm', sql.NVarChar);
    ps.input('fetch', sql.Int);
    ps.input('offset', sql.Int);
    ps.prepare('select * from dbo.udfSearchIssues(@searchterm, @offset, @fetch)',
        function (err) {
            ps.execute({
                    searchterm: searchterm,
                    fetch: fetch,
                    offset: offset
                },
                function (err, recordset) {
                    if (recordset.length === 0) {
                        res.status(404).send('Not Found');
                    } else {
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        res.send(recordset);
                        res.end();
                    }
                });
        });
}

return {
    searchIssues: searchIssues
};
}

module.exports = searchService;
```

My angular client side routing

```
    'use strict';
(function () {
var bugFarmApp = angular.module('bugFarmApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/issue/:issueKey', {
           templateUrl: 'templates/issue.html',
            controller: 'IssueController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/search/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchController',
            resolve: {
                event: function($route, search){
                    return search.getIssues().$promise;
                }
            }
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/search/:searchval', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchController',
            resolve: {
                event: function($route, search){
                    return                       search.getIssuesByVal($route.current.pathParams.searchval)
.$promise;
                }
            }
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

})();
```

searchRoute.js

```
var express = require('express');
var searchRouter = express.Router();

var router = function(){

var searchController = require('../controllers/searchController')();

searchRouter.route('/')
    .get(searchController.getAllIssues);
searchRouter.route('/:searchval')
    .get(searchController.getIssuesByValue);

return searchRouter;
};

module.exports = router;
```

searchController.js

```
var searchController = function () {

var searchService = require('../services/searchService')();

var getAllIssues = function (req, res) {
    searchService.searchIssues(req, res, '');
};


var getIssuesByValue = function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.searchval == undefined) {
        var searchterm = '';   
    } else {
        var searchterm = req.params.searchval;    
    };
    searchService.searchIssues(req, res, searchterm);
};

 return {
    getAllIssues: getAllIssues,
    getIssuesByValue: getIssuesByValue
 };


};

module.exports = searchController;
```

So again just to re-cap, I load my webserver and go to localhost:3000 and everything works fine and index.html is served up. I go to my nav bar and click search and it fires a function in my angular controller which uses the location service to route me over to /search/. If I do this through the UI everything loads and all the html in my search.html template is good.

If I click refresh or try to manually type in the URL it just gives me the JSON I am getting back from SQL.

Sorry if there is something easy but I have been stuck on this for a while and have searched up and down on the forum.

EDIT: I added my express routes to the question
EDIT2: Ryan had the correct solution below. My client side routes and server side routes were using the same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution(and cleaner IMO) is to add a prefix to all of your api routes. Something like

```
// app.js....

//set up routes
var searchRouter = require('./src/webserver/routes/searchRoutes')();
app.use('/api/search', searchRouter);

// ...app.js
```

I don't see the place in your Angular code that makes the actual ajax call to your node service but it looks you are calling it via `search.getIssuesByVal` in your client side routing. The service that makes the call will have something like `$http.get('/search', ....);` You need to change that to match your new api route: `$http.get('/api/search', ....)`.

If you absolutely have to use the same path you would have to use content negotiation. Which means that in angular you would have to set the Accept header to `application/json` and then in all of your routes(or better in middleware) you would check the Accept header to determine if you should serve the index page or json.

Comment: I added my express routes that I have in place. 

I am not sure exactly how to apply the first solution you presented to my code I thought I was already pre-fixing my routes correctly.

Comment: @MichaelScheidegger see my updated answer. You want ajax calls to be served by a different url than what the browser sees in the address bar. Hence adding the /api prefix to all routes that will be called via ajax(Angular $http, $resource, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. I do have a client side service utilizeing the $resource service. I will try the suggestion and post back tomorrow.